# Shared class with @Provider annotation

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jax-rs, quarkus, resteasy

I have three quarkus apps:

- `MyApplesRestApp`
- `MyBananasRestApp`
- `MyTomatoesRestApp`

Those apps reuse some of the classes in a shared common library `FruitServicesLib`.

In `MyApplesRestApp`, I have a straightforward exception handler to map exceptions to an HTTP error 400:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExtensionMapper
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider

@Provider
public class IllegalArgumentExceptionMapper implements ExtensionMapper<IllegalArgumentException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(IllegalArgumentException) {
        returnResponse.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }
}
```

I want to move the exception handler class above to the common library `FruitServicesLib`, but I also want to enable this exception handler in `MyApplesRestApp` and `MyBananasRestApp`, but not in MyTomatoesRestApp.

What's the best way to do that? How can I move a @Provider annotated class to a common library but not have it activated all the time - conditionally enable it when needed (via java code or by using some config)?

Comment: One option is to override the `MyTomatoesRestApp.getClasses()`. What version of Quarkus are you using?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Extend solution**

I implemented this using a simple and straightforward approach, and there's more code in the exception mapper that I want to avoid duplicating.

My solution is to remove the `@Provider` annotation from the library. In `MyApplesRestApp` and `MyBananasRestApp`, I extend the class and add the `@Provider` annotation to enable it in a project.

The exception mapper in the library:

```java
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExtensionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class IllegalArgumentExceptionMapper implements ExtensionMapper<IllegalArgumentException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(IllegalArgumentException) {
        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }
}
```

The exception mapper in `MyApplesRestApp` and `MyBananasRestApp`:

```java
import com.mylib.IllegalArgumentExceptionMapper;

@Provider
public class MyIllegalArgumentExceptionMapper extends IllegalArgumentExceptionMapper {}
```

**2. Another solution that I use also sometimes is to use @IfBuildProperty**

```
@Provider
@IfBuildProperty(name = "common.illegal-exception-mapper.enabled", stringValue = "true")
public class IllegalArgumentExceptionMapper implements ExtensionMapper<IllegalArgumentException> {
...
```

application.properties of the application

```
common.illegal-exception-mapper.enabled=true
```